# База Данных(SQL) на C++ в Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-c++

Привет всем. Мне задали такой курсач: "Автоматизированная система ЗАГСА". Ну понятно что там используется БД. Для этого я сейчас учу SQL. Но у меня нету понятия как я могу мой код на C++ связать с БД. Подскажите как это сделать или есть что-то что можно прочесть?

Comment: Ну, с одной стороны, с Visual Studio органично, так сказать, сочетается IIS... Но я бы советовал посмотреть в сторону  [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: @Harry VS органично сочетается с IIS, поэтому стоит использовать SQLite, я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Вам нужна библиотека для доступа к БД, это может быть ODBC, ADO, или например SQLAPI++ (http://www.sqlapi.com/), у Sql Server есть так же свои библиотеки (SQL Server Native Client)

Comment: @PrimusSingularis Если я вам напишу, что проехать от А до Б можно быстро на такси... но для здоровья полезнее пешком - вы тоже это воспримите как "Проехать от А до Б быстрее на такси, ПОЭТОМУ стоит идти пешком"? Если да - это не ко мне, а к психиатру :) Если нет - перечитайте в свете написанного мой первоначальный комментарий.